# Appropriate datastructure or implementation class for holding a small but changing collection

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency

I have written following [game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) and want to provide a groups feature. Groups will allow to group players together who are "nearby" on screen. In fast action games, this group would be changing fast since players will be moving in and out of their zones constantly.

Since each player would need to listen to events from other players in the group, players will subscribe to the group.
This brings me to my question. What is the appropriate datastructure or java collection class which can be used in this scenario to hold the changing set of event listeners on a group? The number of listeners to a group would rarely exceed 20 in my opinion, and should be lesser than that in most scenarios. It is a multi-threaded environment.

The one I am planning to use is a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But since there will be reasonable amount of updates(due to changing subscriptions) is this class appropriate? What other class would be good to use? If you have any custom implementation using array's etc please share.

Comment: consider subclassing or delegatine to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Comment: I already have an EventDispatcher which does the same as observable. My question is more leaning more towards what is the appropriate data structure to store the "observers" who have registered with the "observable"

Comment: references to the observers are stored in the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do players have integer IDs? If so then I have an **lightweight, immutable array-based set** class that might make sense for you:

- http://code.google.com/p/mikeralib/source/browse/trunk/Mikera/src/main/java/mikera/persistent/IntSet.java

This was written for similar kinds of situations in game engines.

However I also have an **alternative approach to consider**: If you are updating the groups automatically based on vicinity, then you might want to consider *not tracking groups at all*. Instead, consider using a spatial data structure that allows you to quickly search for nearby players whenever an event occurs, and directly send the event to nearby players.

Typically you could use a 2D or 3D grid or octree with the smallest division size set to be equal to the max range for your groups. Then a vicinity search will only need to check 9 (2D case) or 27 (3D case) locations in order to find all nearby players. I think doing this search whenever needed will be faster and simpler than the overhead of maintaining lists of groups and listeners all the time....

Comment: The "not tracking groups at all" option is interesting. The only issue I think will be that each person who writes a game on top of jetserver would in turn need to do implement this logic themselves.

Comment: You should be able to implement it as a standard feature with a few configurable parameters (view radius etc.). Look at it this way: I don't think it would be any more complicated than the grouping logic

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have millions of changes per second (which seems unlikely in your scenario) a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` should be good enough for what you need. If I were you, I would use that.

**IF** you notice a performance issue **AND** you have profiled your application **AND** you have identified that the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is the bottleneck, then you can find a better structure. But I doubt it will be the case.

Comment: I will definitely not have millions of updates. Compared to the number of reads, updates will be fewer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, you have choice between `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ConcurrentHashMap`:

CopyOnWriteArrayList:

1. Add/remove operation computational cost is linear to the size of the list. May happen multiple times during a single iteration (group notification).
2. Simpler data structure with constant read time.

ConcurrentHashMap:

1. Add/remove operation is a constant time operation. Additions or Removal of subscribers do not affect iteration already in progress and blocking is minimized.
2. Larger data structure that requires slightly longer read time.

Creating a custom solution is possible when it comes to efficiency but probably not as safe when it comes to thread safety. I'm leaning towards `ConcurrentHashMap` but the winner will probably depend heavily on how your game turns out.

Comment: Is ConcurrentHashMap a good choice for small sets? I thought it worked well for big ones.

Comment: Like I said, it has a larger structure. But performance will depend on the number of add/remove operations and total size of the subscribers.